# different process's %cpu output via top from busybox and procps-ng

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, busybox, procps

I have an `Embedded Linux(Kernel 2.6.37)` running on `ARM`. There's a default `top` from `busybox 1.13.2`. And I build a `procps-ng 3.3.11` via cross compile to run on this `Linux`. I found that the process's `%cpu` via `top` output from `busybox` and `procps-ng` are different.

For example,  the `%cpu` of one process, `procps-ng top` display about 30%, but `busybox top` display only about 10%. The total `%cpu` from `procps-ng top` and `busybox top` are the same.
Then I read the calculation source code of `busybox` and `procps-ng`. I found that they really have different calculation formula for one process's `%cpu`.

```
- busybox top:  
    CPU% = s->pcpu/sum(s->pcpu) * busy_cpu_ticks/total_cpu_ticks   
    (pcpu is delta of sys+user time between samples)  

- procps-ng top: 
    CPU% = s->pcpu/total_cpu_ticks
```

Why the two projects choose different calculation formula? Do they designed for different application case? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have discussed this issue with the procps-ng team, and here's the key point:

> On 12/28/2016 03:12 PM, Craig Small wrote:
>   There is probably a different ways to look at this. The first thing I would say is that busybox is supposed to be emulating or mimicking what the main programs are supposed to do, so if there is a difference between busybox and the real program, I would say that busybox is wrong. It would be like the busybox ls printing files differently to the real ls.
>
> Let's look at this formula again:
>
> - busybox top:
>     `CPU% = s->pcpu/sum(s->pcpu) * busy_cpu_ticks/total_cpu_ticks`
>     (pcpu is delta of sys+user time between samples)
> - procps-ng top:
>     `CPU% = s->pcpu/total_cpu_ticks`
>
> Now let's re-arrange it:
>
> - busybox top:
>     `CPU% = s->pcpu/total_cpu_ticks  * busy_cpu_ticks/sum(s->pcpu)`
>     `CPU% = top_CPU%  * busy_cpu_ticks/sum(s->pcpu)`
>     (pcpu is delta of sys+user time between samples)
>
> This is the difference. busybox adds a ratio of `busy_cpu_ticks/sum(s->pcpu)` to what top worked out.  This ratio could be written as:
>
> `RATIO = Sum(Usr + Nice + System + Irq + sirq + steal) / Sum(Usr + System)`
>
> You can sort of see this in `read_cpu_jiffy` in the busybox source. I don't 
>    understand what this ratio is trying to do or why it is required. Especially when the program you are trying to emulate doesn't have it.
>
> procps top says out of the total available jiffies in this cycle, X% were used by this program. busybox puts some odd scaling in there. So if a process uses 10% of the CPU in its system and user parts, top shows 10%. If for that cycle The process is in User and System for 50% of the time, busybox would show 20% (10% x 100/50).
>
> I don't know why they did that.

Please refer the discussion link for more details:
[discussion: different process's %cpu output via top from busybox and procps-ng](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues/48)